# How do I show options in select using v-for with Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

The script part:

```html
<script export>
    let categories=ref({})
    let selectedCategory

    onMounted(async () => {
        getCategories()
    })

    const getCategories=async () => {
        let response=await axios.get(`/api/get_all_category/`)
        categories=response.data.categories
        console.log(categories)
    }
</script>
```

The output of console.log(categories) is:

[image]

The template part:

```
<div class="my-3">
  <p>Product type</p>
  <select v-model="selectedCategory">
    <option v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" :value="category.id">
      {{ category.name }}
     </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

But no, checking the page the select has no options:

[image]

There are no other warnings or errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `export` in `<script export>` by `setup`, and `.value` when you assign the respone to `categories` :

```html
<script setup>
      let categories = ref([])
      let selectedCategory=ref([])
    
      onMounted(async () => {
        getCategories()
      })
    
      const getCategories = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get(`/api/get_all_category/`)
        categories.value = response.data.categories
        console.log(categories)
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did not solve it.

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Comment: Zero errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: You missed `.value` when assigning, it should `categories.value = response.data.categories`

Comment: categories and selectedCategory are an array and object accordingly, not the opposite. The way it works now shouldn't cause problems with Vue 3, but it's not guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Categories is a array, then: var categories = reactive([]); no ref.